# is there a way to fake (i.e. not even mocking) an Actor system

Tags: scala, akka

I have a Service class that takes an actor system at construction time. Some of the method of the service use spray client, that's the reason.

For testing other method of the class i need to provide for a dump actor system simply for the initialization of the class. Is there a way to get a dump actor system, i don't even need to mock it.

One solution that i see is to wrap my actor system in an option and have some logic in the code that would deal with. Then that would allow me to test the method of of my service that do not need it. I would instantiate my class with None for the purpose of the test.

But that is just too trick for so little.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I think my question is clear bob. Given that i am in the rush, i just don't mock it. that's it. I have a service that takes an actor system in parameter and i supply it when i run my test suite and shut it down within BeforeAll trait.

Comment: I have about 3 method that make use of the actor system and only one that does not.